# Generate excel sheet from classic asp on click of button

Tags: asp-classic, export-to-excel

I want to create an excel sheet from click of button.
These excel sheet will contain report which is generated on classic asp page. When user clicks on button then an excel sheet should be created which will have the same report as page have

Comment: Please post what you have already tried.

Comment: I Google and tried to include response.content type() n response.add header but when I include these two line in my page then page gives error.   Iam new to these concept so I don't know how to start these code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This header works fine:

```
 <%
  Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=NOMBRE_ARCHIVO.xls"  
  Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel" 
 %>
```

For small tables, try this example in html/javascript:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <table id="tabla" border="1">
            <tr><th>Uno</th><td>1</td></tr>
            <tr><th>Dos</th><td>2</td></tr>         
        </table>
        <p>
            <input type="button" onclick="javascript:exportarExcel('tabla');" value="Vamos al excel!">
        </p>
    </body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function exportarExcel(tabla){
        var t = document.getElementById(tabla);
        t.border = 1;
        var html = t.outerHTML;
        html = encodeURIComponent(html);
        // problemas con el encoding!
        // se puede usar base64_encode() en lugar de encodeURIComponent(html))
        // ojo con encodeURIComponet() que está deprecada. lo mejor sería usar base64

        window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + html);
    }
    </script>

</html>
```