# Classic asp code to export data from Access database to an Excel sheet

Tags: html, asp.net, database, excel, ms-access

I have an application running in classic ASP coding with HTML pages and in one `.asp` page the client requested for a button. This button when clicked, it must export whatever the data present in a Table of Access database (already in use) to an excel sheet.

Comment: Please add some code, SO isn't here to do the work for you

Comment: This link can help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29791594/generate-excel-sheet-from-classic-asp-on-click-of-button

Comment: Consider there is a table 'Users' in MS Access Database 'Sample'. Now we need to open a connection, retrieve the data from 'Users' table and place it in a new excel sheet(excel must be created through our code). We can make use of VB scripting too.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a file with the xls extension with an HTML table and Excel will open (with a warning) just fine. Example:

text.asp

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<%

    Response.clear
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
    Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=ExportedData.xls"
    Response.Write "<table>"
    Response.Write "<tr><th>User</th></tr>"

    set rs = ListUsers()
    if not rs.EOF Then
        Do while not rs.eof
            Response.Write "<tr><td>" + rs("User") + "</td></tr>"
            Rs.movenext
        loop
    end if


    Response.Write "</table>"
    Response.end
%>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this code take data from MS Access database or the data that is present in 2D form in HTML table?

Comment: It's all server side